# javascript video dom onstalled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video dom
Why does dom execute a onstalled after switching the browser tab before or during resource loading

Now, I just added a retry plan，Is there a better solution?

My goal is to switch the browser tab dom to load the resource successfully

thanks

```js
let dom = document.createElement('video');
dom.preload = 'metadata';
dom.muted = true;
dom.onloadedmetadata = function() {
}
dom.onseeked = function() {
}
let t;
dom.onstalled = () => {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    dom.load();
  },1000);
}
dom.src = url;
```

Comment: according to this SO u need top stop loading and clear src before start loading again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105950/html5-video-stalled-event

Comment: maybe this also relevant In case you are using chrome then follow the following steps

Go to Settings > Advanced > System - Un-check 'Use hardware acceleration when available' & relaunch Chrome.

Comment: @johnSmith Disappointed, it does not solve my problem, but thanks for your answer